# Why doesn't “setContentView” work in if statement?

Tags: android

the code is in onCreate! when `setContentView(R.layout.manual);` is outside the `if` it works. But I moved `setContentView(R.layout.manual);` into `if` can’t work!

The followign:

```
if (settings.getBoolean("my_first_time", true)) { 
    setContentView(R.layout.manual); // can not work
}
```

But `Log.d("Comments1", "First time");` always works

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    if (settings.getBoolean("my_first_time", true)) {

        //the app is being launched for first time, do something 

        Log.d("Comments1", "First time");//this can be showed on logCat!

        setContentView(R.layout.manual);// this can not work 

        // record the fact that the app has been started at least once
        settings.edit().putBoolean("my_first_time", false).commit(); 
        }

}
```

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.manual);    use like that because if condition may be false.

Comment: Post the complete onCreate code.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is not getting satisfied because

```
settings.getBoolean("my_first_time", true)
```

is not returning true.
Hence your

> setContentView(R.layout.manual)

is not called inside the “if” block.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know what you are doing if you set a if-else loop, because no matter what is the outcome `setContentView()` must be supplied with a valid layout id. If you have a condition to check before setting the layout, you can just check the id:

```
int layoutId=0;
if(condition) {
    layoutId = R.layout.manual;
} else {
    layoutId = R.layout.other;
}
setContentView(layoutId);
```